# Squire Mock Model not working with lists

Tags: requirejs, ractivejs, squirejs

In my Squire spec, I am mocking the model my controller takes. The controller dynamically adds a list of objects to the model, but it's not there when the spec runs the expectation. It works when a String parameter is dynamically added to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by returning a promise when setting the array on the model and executing my expectation on return of the promise from the method I was testing.